# Absorb data from dxf texts to near lines

Tags: spatial-join, dxf, text

So, I have 2 dxf files, one with lines and another with nodes (they used to be texts measuring the lines), and I need to extract the text from those nodes and assign it to their corresponding lines.
Theres exactly one node for every line, at a distance of around 2 or 4 map units from the corresponding counterpart. I need to join them but adjusting max distance to those 2 or 4 units and also selecting the node with the most close text to the real measure (I mean, if a line is 50mts long and the closest node's text says 6mts, then thas not the right line, avoid it and keep searching more nodes in the specified radius. Thought about using a tolerance, fixed or porcentual)
I dont have a clue about how to do this. I could use a script, even a not efficient one, because is a one time task...

This is what I have got from cadists...
[image: Before]

And this is what I need to accomplish
[image: After]

Im using QGis 3.10

Comment: What GIS software are you using?